# Microsoft Access 2010 Link Data Service to SOAP web service

Tags: web-services, soap, ms-access-2010

I have been tasked with calling a web service from Microsoft Access 2010 when a row is inserted into a table.

As far as I can work out, with Access 2010 you can use "Link Data Service" and aparently this can work with a SOAP web service but when I "Install a new connection" (that is looknig for an xml file) and enter the link to the WSDL it throws an error expecting a root node of "Model" and not "wsdl:definitions".

Has anybody used "Link Data Service" and is it possible to use with a SOAP web service?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should install the previous version of the Office Web Services toolkit, and then you can easily create proxy objects that call the methods of your WSDL.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2224